# Ассимиляция в лингвистике

Tags: недопустимая-метка

"С сегодняшнего" - есть ли здесь ассимиляция?

Answer (score 2):

Не вижу ни оглушения, ни озвончения, ни смягчения под воздействием соседних звуков. Здесь только традиционное написание окончания его, хотя слышится ево -ева. Это не фонетические изменения.

**Дополнение к ответу.**
Подумала над ответом  Sibilla, видимо, она права. Это регрессивная  ассимиляция по мягкости. Просто я помню, что смягчение **в современном русском** происходит внутри слова, но отсутствует перед мягким согласным следующего слова.([вот - л'ес]) А вообще, действие ассимиляции в современном русском литературном языке не всегда отличается строгой последовательностью.

Смягчение [з], [с] происходит  на конце приставок и созвучных с ними предлогов перед мягкими губными: [ръз'д'иел'ит'], [ръс'т'иенут'], [б'ьез'-н'иево), [б'иес'- с'ил] (разделить, растянуть, без него, без сил). Перед мягкими губными смягчение [з], [с], [д], [т] возможно внутри корня и на конце приставок на -з,  а также в приставке с- и в созвучном с ней **предлоге**: [с'м'ех], [з'в'eр'], [д'в'eр'],[т'в'eр'], [с'п'eт'], [с'-н'им], [ис'-пeч'], [рΛз'д'eт'] (смех, зверь, дверь, Тверь, спеть, с ним, испечь, раздеть). Губные перед мягкими зубными не смягчаются: [пт'eн'ч'ьк], [н'ефт'], [вз'ат'] (птенчик, нефть, взять В приставке с- и в созвучном с ней предлоге: [с'м'ех], [з'в'eр'], [д'в'eр'],[т'в'eр'], [с'п'eт'], [с'-н'им], [ис'-пeч'], [рΛз'д'eт'] (смех, зверь, дверь, Тверь, спеть, с ним, испечь, раздеть). Губные перед мягкими зубными не смягчаются: [пт'eн'ч'ьк], [н'ефт'], [вз'ат'] (птенчик, нефть, взять).

А у нас **другой**, интересный случай, когда **предлог** сливается с первым корневым звуком. Долгим назвать его нельзя, долгие у нас только внутри одной морфемы ж и щ в словах дрожжи и щи, а вот двойной - да.  А если это двойной звук, то про первый можно сказать, что здесь ассимиляция под воздействием второго.

Но нужно взять во внимание и **необязательность** процесса ассимиляции.Это **возможно** при быстром произнесении, а если произнести дистанционно С СЕГОДНЯШНЕГО, то и смягчения нет.

Но здесь, видимо, учебное задание, поэтому если возможно , надо засчитывать.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я помню, ассимиляция - это уподобление. В начале слова мы можем услышать долгий звук С, предлог сливается с первым звуком корня. А в остальном я согласна с Людмилой: в окончании слова Г произносится как В. Ассимиляции я тоже не вижу.

Answer (score 0):

**Как вариант:** может быть, здесь ассимиляция твердой приставки  С перед мягкой корневой С в начале слова с последующим удвоением  согласных (геминацией).

Геминация, или удвоение (лат. gemino — «удваиваю») — в фонетике более продолжительное произнесение согласного звука.

Comment: И тогда С становится одним долгим палатализованным (т.е.смягчённым) согласным. А палатализация - это разновидность ассимиляции. Вы умница, Sibilla.

Comment: Нету там ассимиляции. И быть не может. С не относится к числу звуков, подверженных прогрессивной ассимиляции по мягкости. Да и в "долгий" звук не превращается.  Сравните "ссора" и  "с сором".

Comment: Видимо, мы с Вами неправы. Это регрессивная ассимиляция (последующий  более сильный, влияет на предыдущий)